# Twilio Connecting to flask socketio problem

Tags: flask, websocket, twilio, twilio-api, flask-socketio

I am trying to connect via flask socketio twilio, elevenlabs and gpt. So ti managed to do some of the things needed for it to work, but i still have problems. First and main one is that i am not recieving any audio when i make call with twilio. I am not sure where is the problem. Is the problem in my url, but i managed to send messages from javascript client via that url, or is it in the way i make connection. If you can review the code guys, and tell me what i am doing wrong, maybe i am not even emitting my data to twilio, or it is the wrong format (but i bbelive that i whould hear something then at least). This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Connect
from elevenlabs import generate
import openai
import re
import base64
import subprocess

# Setting up outbound calls client
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
my_number = os.environ['MY_NUMBER']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
vlada = '+381600781823'
# Set your OpenAI API key here
openai.api_key = os.environ['OPENAI_KEY']
elevenlabs_key = os.environ['ELEVENLABS_KEY']

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")


def convert_raw_audio_generator_to_mulaw(raw_audio_generator):
  # Define the FFmpeg command
  ffmpeg_command = [
    'ffmpeg',
    '-f',
    's16le',  # Input format (16-bit little-endian)
    '-ar',
    '44100',  # Input sample rate
    '-ac',
    '1',  # Input channels (mono)
    '-i',
    'pipe:0',  # Input from stdin
    '-f',
    'mulaw',  # Output format (mulaw)
    '-ar',
    '8000',  # Output sample rate
    '-ac',
    '1',  # Output channels (mono)
    'pipe:1'  # Output to stdout
  ]

  try:
    # Start the FFmpeg process
    ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_command,
                                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    # Process raw audio data from the generator in chunks
    for chunk in raw_audio_generator:
      # Write the chunk to FFmpeg's stdin
      ffmpeg_process.stdin.write(chunk)

    # Close stdin to signal the end of input
    ffmpeg_process.stdin.close()

    # Wait for FFmpeg to finish
    ffmpeg_process.wait()

    # Check for errors
    if ffmpeg_process.returncode != 0:
      raise Exception(
        f'FFmpeg error: {ffmpeg_process.stderr.read().decode("utf-8")}')

    # Get the mulaw-encoded audio from FFmpeg's stdout
    mulaw_audio = ffmpeg_process.stdout.read()

    # Encode the mulaw audio as base64
    base64_audio = base64.b64encode(mulaw_audio).decode()

    return base64_audio

  except Exception as e:
    print(f'Error: {str(e)}')
    return None


def makecall(to):
  call = client.calls.create(to=to,
                             url='https://test.vladastefanovic.repl.co/voice',
                             from_=my_number)
  print('Call made!')
  return call


def send_audio(audio_data):
  # Emit the 'audio_data' event to the server
  print('Send audio called!')
  converted_audio = convert_raw_audio_generator_to_mulaw(audio_data)
  socketio.emit('audio_data', converted_audio)


# Getting stream chunks out of AI prompt
def write(prompt: str):
  sentence_ending = re.compile(
    r"[.!?]")  # Regular expression to match sentence endings
  generated_text = ""  # Initialize the generated text

  for chunk in openai.ChatCompletion.create(
      model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages=[{
        "role": "user",
        "content": prompt
      }],
      temperature=0.5,
      stream=True,
  ):
    if (text_chunk := chunk["choices"][0]["delta"].get("content")) is not None:
      generated_text += text_chunk  # Append the text_chunk to the generated_text

      # Check if the generated_text ends with a sentence-ending punctuation
      if sentence_ending.search(generated_text):
        yield generated_text
        generated_text = ""


def start_sending():
  text_stream = write(
    prompt=
    "Write me some few words 'hmm' like message as the first sentence.Write me an essay about World War Two. Include at least two sentences."
  )
  # Iterate over the text_stream generator and send each chunk
  for chunk in text_stream:
    audio_stream = generate(
      text=str(chunk),
      model="eleven_monolingual_v1",
      stream=True,
      api_key=elevenlabs_key,
    )
    send_audio(audio_stream)


@app.route("/")
def index():
  return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/make_call")
def make_call():
  makecall(vlada)
  # start_sending()
  return 'Hello'


# @app.route("/send_message")
# def send_message():
#   socketio.emit('message', "Nesto radim sve mu jebem!")
#   return render_template('send_message.html')

# @socketio.on('message')
# def handle_message(message):
#   print(f'GOT message: {message}')


@app.route("/voice", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def voice():
  print('Call ongoing')
  response = VoiceResponse()
  connect = Connect()
  connect.stream(url='wss://test.vladastefanovic.repl.co')
  start_sending()
  return str(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  socketio.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=7000)
```

I tried everything i could came up with